# rails console is maxing out Mac memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Mac OSX 12.1. I have some rails 6 apps and they are working normally in regard to memory usage.

But rails 5.2.6 has a strange memory issue.  When I start a rails server or run rspec, the usage of the CPU is normal i.e. low when not much is happening but higher when large tests or heavy server usage occurs.

However, when I use `rails console` the CPU usage climbs almost immediately to over 100%, and pretty soon the Mac fan starts to run. It stays this way even if I exit the console. I have to do `killall ruby` to stop all ruby processes.  I am monitoring memory using `top -o cpu`.  Is this a known issue with rails 5.2.6? Is there a way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem for quite a while. I've eventually noticed that it's a problem with the `listen` gem. Updating it is enough to fix it.

Update it to the latest version possible. If I remember correctly, it has to be at least `v3.3` for the problem to go away.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check what initializes when you do `rails c`. You def should profile your startup times. Start checking your `config/initializers` folder and also consider [Profiling Rails Boot Time](https://mildlyinternet.com/code/profiling-rails-boot-time.html). Also check how to [Speed up Rails boot time](https://dev.to/hlmerscher/speeding-up-rails-boot-time-ie9).

I don't believe this is specific to 5.2.6 but make sure you use at least ruby 2.7.0 ish which also affects your performance.

[image: Ruby benchmarks]

Comment: These are all good things to do, but Dharman's answer solved the problem. I am using ruby 2.7.4.

Comment: Just in case someone will be searching for the solution, it was my answer (not Dharman's).